# Collection modified during foreach error

Tags: c#, .net, collections, foreach, iterator

I know you can't modify a collection during a `foreach`, but I should be able to set variable values of the underlying iterator through it. For some reason the method below, every time it executes is giving be the "Collection was modified..." error:

```
private static IInstrument AdjustForSimpleInstrument(DateTime valueDate, IInstrument temp)
{
    var instr = temp;
    foreach (var component in instr.Components)
    {
        component.Schedule.ScheduleRows.RemoveAll(
                sr =>
                ((sr.Payment != null) && (sr.Payment.PaymentDate != null) &&
                 (sr.Payment.PaymentDate.AdjustedDate.Date <= valueDate.Date)));

        if (
            !component.ScheduleInputs.ScheduleType.In(ComponentType.Floating, ComponentType.FloatingLeg,
                                                      ComponentType.Cap, ComponentType.Floor)) continue;

        foreach (var row in component.Schedule.ScheduleRows)
        {
            var clearRate = false;
            if (row.Payment.CompoundingPeriods != null)
            {
                if (row.Payment.CompoundingPeriods.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (
                        var period in
                            row.Payment.CompoundingPeriods.Where(
                                period => ((FloatingRate)period.Rate).ResetDate.FixingDate > valueDate))
                    {
                        period.Rate.IndexRate = null;
                        clearRate = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (row.Payment.PaymentRate is FloatingRate)
            {
                if (((FloatingRate)row.Payment.PaymentRate).ResetDate.FixingDate > valueDate)
                    clearRate = true;
            }
            else if (row.Payment.PaymentRate is MultipleResetRate)
            {
                if (
                    ((MultipleResetRate)row.Payment.PaymentRate).ChildRates.Any(
                        rate => rate.ResetDate.FixingDate > valueDate))
                {
                    clearRate = true;
                }
            }
            if (clearRate)
            {
                row.Payment.PaymentRate.IndexRate = null;
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Am I just missing something easy here? The loop that is causing the exception is the second, this one:

```
foreach (var row in component.Schedule.ScheduleRows)
```

Comment: there are multiple loops, you should specify which one is causing the exception...

Comment: You should also consider refactoring this method into 2 or 3 methods. You're doing a lot in nested loops and the conditional nesting is getting deep.

Comment: Yeah actually in the middle of refactoring now, but in testing found this error and trying to figure out why..

Comment: Also nested ifs. Consider changing to if(condition1 && condition2) to compact the method further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is not .NET-framework stuff, so I assume that row is connected to its collection. Modifying the contents of the row, might shift its place inside its collection, thus modifying the collection, which is not allowed during some foreach-operations.

The solution is simple: create a copy of the collection (by using LINQ).

```
foreach (var row in component.Schedule.ScheduleRows.ToList())
    ...
```